# ASP.net Rejuicer combine js dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im looking at using Rejuicer http://rejuice.me/ to combine all the JS files of my ASP.net MVC site into one JS file.  This works ok  but it doesnt allow me to add or remove JS files without having to also reset/recycle the application, as all the configuration is set in the Application_Start() event handler.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this. Or if there is a better alternative to Rejuicer?

Answer (score 1):

Loading configuration in Application_Start is a trade off. Other option is to hook into FileSystemWatcher and wait for folder changes. Given the nature of a web application, this isn't ideal. Some alternative use web.config which also forces a reset.

There are tools like [Workbench](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) which does its thing during development (in VS.NET). This removes dependency on the application start cycle and files are there when the app starts up.

Comment: I had thought of the web.config idea, but i felt a bit weird about listing js files in there.

Comment: not sure if you get notified of updates to the question, but I have added a possible solution and would like to know your thoughts

Comment: Your sample above compares only the count of files. Adding or removing files will be covered. But content changes in a particular js file won't be. Can you explain what is your primary concern with resetting the app? Typically, this is uncommon in production and in dev, resetting is not a big deal. I personally prefer development time 'juicing'!

Comment: Rejuicer itself detects changes to the js files, so i dont think i need to worry about that.  I work with strictly front end devs who dont edit the web.config or IIS settings. Also I have some clients that we send code to for deployment (we have no control over Produciton) and they request that we only send the files that have changed. Bit of a pain i know.

Answer (score 0):

In the _layout.cshtml file I have code similar to this. The list of js files for the site can be defined here without having to reset or recompile the site.

```
@{

    //combine all JS files into one file using Rejuicer. 
    List<string> JsFiles = new List<string>();

    //define list of JS files here
    JsFiles.Add("~/Scripts/One.js");
    JsFiles.Add("~/Scripts/Two.js");      


    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["JsFileListing"] != null)
    {

        var JsFileRejuiced = (List<string>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["JsFileListing"];

        //check if we have any new/removed/renamed files
        if (JsFiles.Except(JsFileRejuiced).Count()> 0 || JsFileRejuiced.Except(JsFiles).Count() > 0)          
        {
            //force application reset
            HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();                
        }
    }

    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["JsFileListing"] == null)
    {

        var Combiner = Rejuicer.OnRequest.ForJs("~/Combined.js").Combine;

        foreach (var file in JsFiles)
        {
            Combiner.File(file);
        }
        Combiner.Configure();

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["JsFileListing"] = JsFiles;
    }
}
@Rejuicer.Rejuiced.JsFor("~/Combined.js")
```